# SumatraPDF Inverse Search

Tags: pdf, pdftex, forward-inverse-search

I wanted to set the SumatraPDF Inverse-Search option on Inlage, according to [instructions on this page](http://www.inlage.com/wiki/setting_up_sumatra_pdf).

For some reason, my "options" menu ends at "Make SumatraPDF my default PDF reader" and doesn't show the "set inverse-search command-line" option. I have the latest 2.0.1 version. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the window is too small. Can you resize it?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be a window size problem. Could it be that the option is not enabled for some reason?

Comment: I don’t know. I’m using Skim on a Mac …

Answer (score 4):

With the official version you once have to use the command line option `-inverse-search`. The setting is saved then and can later be changed via the option dialogue.

Using the path from the Inlage wiki and assuming SumatraPDF is installed in the same path:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Inlage 4\Inlage 4.exe\" \"%f\" -n%l"`

Comment: Thanks. But where do I use the command line? I have a windows machine

Comment: @PineApple: The command line terminal in Windows is called “Command Prompt”, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt (where versions in other languages are linked, as usual for Wikipedia).

Comment: I think in the latest SumatraPDF version this is the only possibility to set the inverse-search line. FYI: The next Inlage version will do that automatically.

Answer (score 3):

This should be a comment but I do not have enough rep.

You are probably using the portable version. Installing gives me the option while the portable version does not.

You should still be able to use the command line argument as in Speravir's answer to set the editor. The setting will be saved to a .dat file which will be read at every startup.

Comment: Ah, thanks for this addition. I use the portable version, too!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the SumatraPDF Version from [this](http://william.famille-blum.org/software/sumatra/index.html) website. This should give you the desired "set inverse-search command-line" in the options menu.

Comment: No, he/she does not have to, but it’s more comfortable with William Blum’s version. With the official version one have to use the command line.

Answer (score 0):

In SumatraPDF-settings.txt (that can be accessed from the Menu **Settings>Advanced Options**) make:

**EnableTeXEnhancements = true**